# systemd failed to stop services form a target

Tags: linux, systemd, services

I'm working on a systemd target which will start a bunch of services when i run `systemct start name.target`. However, i was unable to stop the services form the target using `systemct stop name.target`. Command executes without any errors. when i check the status of services individually, i can see those services are still running.

this is my target which starts few services.

```
[Unit]
Description=Main Components service target(name.target)
Requires=c1.service c2.service c3.service
# or
# Wants=

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`systemctl enable name.target` and `systemctl start name.target` these commands will enable and start the target. this way i am able to start all the services mentioned in the target.
`systemctl stop name.target` command runs without any error, but doesnot stop the services.

Template of the services (c1,c2,c3)

```
[Unit]
Description=c1 Component Script
After=mainApp.service
PartOf=name.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/root/script.sh
Restart=always
```

if i run `systemctl stop c1.service` command, this will stop the service.
i want to stop all the services in the target just like how i started them, can this be possible?

Comment: Isn't the recommended way to "start" and "stop" targets `systemctl isolate some.target` / `systemctl isolate some-other-target` ?

Comment: ... see for example [systemctl isolate - what's the reasoning behind the word "isolate"?](https://superuser.com/questions/1168879/systemctl-isolate-whats-the-reasoning-behind-the-word-isolate)